# Python Openpyxl - Append many excel files into 1 file

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have 10 Excel files (they have same number of columns, and varying number of rows)

I need to append data from those 10 files into one single Excel file using Openpyxl Python library

Read data from File1, append it to new_file
Read data from File2, append it to new_file
...

Is this possible? Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Certainly possible. You state 10 files so that is 10 Excel workbooks (wb) where you want to copy the rows from a sheet in the 1st wb to Sheet1 in a new wb, then copy the rows from a sheet in the 2nd wb and also append to Sheet1 in the new wb so this data is added immediately below the data from 1st wb? Then same with 3rd wb and so on. What about headers? Do these exist (in each wb), are they the same for each of the 10, if so then presume you'd only want these copied once from the first wb? Any formatting on the data you wish to preserve?

Comment: Thank you. There are no headers, just raw data that I need to combine into one Excel file. They are all on Sheet1, and I need to put them on the Sheet1 of a new document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some missing details in the question, as raised by @moken. Let's make some assumptions that all files have a single sheet named 'Sheet 1' and identical column headers. And the final output will start with file10's content, then file9 etc and we will skip copying the column headers.

For the sake of simplicity, we will use 3 files' content for illustration:

file1.xlsx:

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F1-1 | F1-2 | F1-3 |

file2.xlsx:

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F2-1 | F2-2 | F2-3 |
| F2-2 | F2-3 | F2-4 |

file3.xlsx:

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F3-1 | F3-2 | F3-3 |
| F3-2 | F3-3 | F3-4 |
| F3-3 | F3-4 | F3-5 |

The code is rather straightforward, where we get all rows from the current file and append row by row to the main workbook:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
main_workbook = load_workbook(filename="file3.xlsx")
file_list = ["file2.xlsx","file1.xlsx"]

for file in file_list:
    workbook = load_workbook(filename=file)
    new_rows = list(workbook['Sheet1'].values)
    for idx,row in enumerate(new_rows):
        # skip column header
        if idx == 0: continue
        main_workbook['Sheet1'].append(row)
    workbook.close()
main_workbook.save("merged.xlsx")
```

The final output would have rows with the following values:

```
>>> list(main_workbook['Sheet1'].values)
[('col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3'),
 ('F3-1', 'F3-2', 'F3-3'),
 ('F3-2', 'F3-3', 'F3-4'),
 ('F3-3', 'F3-4', 'F3-5'),
 ('F2-1', 'F2-2', 'F2-3'),
 ('F2-2', 'F2-3', 'F2-4'),
 ('F1-1', 'F1-2', 'F1-3')]
```